# Named values remain the same

Tags: vba, excel

I'm facing a design issue here with VBA. I'm loading data from multiple workbooks with references to certain Named Values. However, the issue is that the Named Values are all the same. So essentially when I'm evaluating the data, it shows each time the same value independent of the workbook I'm loading the named values from.

This is due due to the fact that the Named Manager only can carry one reference at a time. How can I make sure I capture the correct reference? Is there a way for example to enforce Excel to replace/clean the Named Values with and make the correct reference, i.e. perform a data purge?

Code example:

```
  Do While fileName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
    Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(Sheet3).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count) ' in this workbook sheet there are references to named values (for all the workbooks loaded, the name of the named values is the same
      With wsCalculations
             .Cells(j, i).Value = "=" + ary(0)
             .Cells(j, i + 1).Value = "=" + ary(1)
       End With
     Workbooks(fileName).Close
   Loop
```

Furthermore: I note that when deleting the named values (workbook scoped and defined on the copied sheets themselves), they are not actually being deleted but recreated as soon as deleted, both via the name manager and VBA code. How can I delete these references so that they won't be recreated?

Many thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a little code for an example?

Comment: Are the references to workbook-scoped names, or sheet-scoped ones?  Are the range sources defined on the sheet being copied? May be useful to add a bit more detail on exactly what type of Names you're dealing with...

Comment: Hi Tim, the scope is workbook. The range sources are indeed defined on the sheet being copied. For some reason, when I delete them through VBA they won't be deleted at all.. they still refer to the extenral path (C:\data\..)

Comment: Because the names are at the workbook level, they will always reference that workbook. you are going to move them down to the worksheet level.

Comment: so if I change the scope to worksheet and then delete them it will work?

Comment: If I set up two workbooks, each with a sheet referring a workbook-level defined name (same name in each), and then copy one of the sheets to the other workbook, then the copied sheet's name gets switched to worksheet-level, and still seems to reference the correct value...

Comment: That is different behavior from what I'm seeing here..

Comment: I deleted the copied sheet and still the named values and their references are showing in the name manager..